# SpriteKit - iPhone 6 Plus - 2x images being loaded?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using a combination of xcasses and sktextureatlases to load images.  I've named all my desired 6 plus images with a 3x extension.  However, when loading my app everything is created as 2x..  What am I doing wrong?

**I noticed when I don't use a launch screen file it seems to work?  What is going on here?**

[image]

[image]

I load images this way

```
let baseImage = UIImage(named: "base")
```

I load the texture atlas for my sprites and it picks the 2x image..  what do i do?

Comment: i noticed that using a xib file i have an issue, but if i create launch images in my xcassets folder i dont have a problem

Comment: it's (xc)assets, not what you wrote ;)

Comment: Did you get this to work, how? I do use LaunchScreen.xib as per the Xcode6 game sprite kit template, but for iPhone 6 Plus the sprites loaded from atlas is always the 2x ones, even though iPhone 6 Plus seems to launch in 414x736 point mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146685/spritekit-not-loading-3x-images-from-sktextureatlas

i followed this.. but even then my game didnt look right to me.  I just used ended up using all the 2x assets for the iphone 6 plus and let it scale it for the bigger screen