# How to make different objects compatible with IPhone and IPad using Spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit, compatibility, sklabelnode

So I've been trying to make all my objects the correct size for both IPad and IPhone by using proportions based on the size of the screen. But I've been having trouble doing it with objects such as the SKLabelNode, due to it using fontSize instead of a (width, height) format. Say I wanted to make this SKLabelNode of fontSize 35 on IPhone 6, how would I use proportions to make it the same size relative to the screen for the IPad 2 so that it works for both the IPhone AND IPad?

```
    SKLabelNode *myLabel2;
    myLabel2 = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"HelveticaNeue-Light"];
    myLabel2.text=@"Click";
    myLabel2.fontSize = 35;
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer on this issue. Part of it deals specifically for SKLabelNode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198878/constraining-proportions-of-gui-elements-in-spritekit-game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible

> The frame property provides the bounding rectangle for a node’s visual
>   content, modified by the scale and rotation properties. The frame is
>   non-empty if the node’s class draws content. Each node subclass
>   determines the size of this content differently. In some subclasses,
>   the size of the node’s content is declared explicitly, such as in the
>   SKSpriteNode class. In other subclasses, the content size is
>   calculated implicitly by the class using other object properties. For
>   example, an SKLabelNode object determines its content size using the
>   label’s message text and font characteristics.

Comment: This did not actually work for me. It says "Expression is not assignable"

Comment: @VarunWadhwa Yes, it was an incorrect answer. See the updated answer.