# Universal 2D Game Assets and Absolute Node Positioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

I have a question regarding **universal game assets** and **absolute positioning** of a `SKNodes` in `Sprite Kit` (iOS 8+).

*I will try to present my problem through an example as follows*:

Imagine a *2D top down game* with a `SKSpriteNode` which represents a house. A house has multiple child `SKSpriteNode`s which represent chairs, desk, sofa, etc.

I have 3 versions of house asset:

- `1x - 200 x 200px` (Non-retina iPads),
- `2x - 400 x 400px` (Retina iPhones and iPads),
- `3x - 600 x 600px` (iPhone 6 Plus).

**Important**:
Child nodes (chairs, desk, etc.) positions are defined in a **.plist file**. Something like this (JSON representation):

```
children: [
    {
        position = {20,20};
    },
    ...
]
```

Since the position is defined in points and not in pixels, everything gets positioned like expected according to device screen scale. For `1x` devices the position stays `{20,20}`, for `2x` position is `{40,40}` and for `3x` the position is `{60,60}`.

**Problem**:

The problem is that `200x200px` and `400x400px` assets are **way to small for iPad devices** in order to achieve similar look and feel on all devices.

**Question**:

> How to successfully present/import assets in a way that would enable
>   me to achieve similar (if not the same) look and feel on all
>   devices/screen sizes without breaking child nodes positioning?

*My takes:*

**Take 1**:

I could simply use the existing `400x400px` assets on Non-retina iPad devices and `600x600px` assets on Retina iPad devices for the house node but the positioning of a child nodes would become broken. This is because the child position value wouldn't change and would still be `{20,20}` and `{40,40}` for iPad devices respectively, while the assets would be bigger. This would yield inaccurate child positions relative to the house node.

**Take 2**:

I could also scale the `SKScene` size (zoom effect) while using the normal `200x200px` and `400x400px` sized assets for iPad devices respectively. This works and it keeps the child nodes positioning working but the rendered quality of the scene/assets is not good as it should be. Also, this feels like a hack and we don't want that.

**Take 3**:

I could also use twice as big assets for iPad devices and double the child nodes position at the runtime. In this case I would use a `400x400px` asset for non-retina iPad devices and a new `800x800px` asset for retina iPad devices. While this looks great and keeps the child nodes positioning working, it seems like a really big hack fixing child node position during runtime with this:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    position.x *= 2.0f;
    position.y *= 2.0f;
}
```

---

*Thank you for taking the time to read the question!*

Comment: At some point you will have to add additional code to make your app universal and using a multiplier, as you suggest in #3, is the best way to go.

Comment: yes, simply use 3. that's essentially how all vid games work. there is absolutely no problem if you end up using "pointlessly too high res" sprites on the "lower-res" screens.

Comment: I did answer a similar bounty but it wasn't addressing iPad. You may find it useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/29269507/851041

Comment: @Joe Blow: There's a performance hit when using pointlessly too hi-res images for low-end devices. rescaling big images loads the CPU and the too big images wastes a lot of system memory, which are two scarce resources especially on older low-end devices!

Comment: hey @salocinx all I can say is, I've never seen the slightest problem, for real-world apps in the wild, as of this year you know ... your mileage may vary!

Comment: @Joe Blow: Sure, for (very) small projects it may not depend. But as soon as a project grows, you have to economice CPU/RAM resources. It costs little extra effort in the starting phase of a project, but is a huge effort when you need to change things in the finish phase. Therefore I recommend everyone to keep in mind using these resources wisely/economically from beginning on... Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I could simply use the existing 400x400px assets on Non-retina iPad
>   devices and 600x600px assets on Retina iPad devices for the house node
>   but the positioning of a child nodes would become broken. This is
>   because the child position value wouldn't change and would still be
>   {20,20} and {40,40} for iPad devices respectively, while the assets
>   would be bigger. This would yield inaccurate child positions relative
>   to the house node.

You can simply scale your house node (not the scene) to a larger size. All you need to do is set the scale on your house to a value that looks good on larger devices. And in fact, instead of checking for iPad we can come up with a formula that sets the scale depending on the size of the screen. Something like the code below should work. Note that it assumes your house is positioned perfectly on a iPhone 4 and it will consistently scale to all larger screens. Note that you really could pick any arbitrary size as your base case, but choosing the smallest screen and scaling up is easiest. Just be sure to provide larger textures so that the textures don't become blurry when scaled.

```
[house setScale:self.scene.size.width/320.0];
```

**OR**

You could use two nodes. A root node for holding the "actual" position, and then an image node child for displaying the image. This will allow you to separate your positional data from what's being displayed. You could resize and position your child image node however you want without messing with the actual position of the root node. You could even include this extra image node data in your JSON.

---

> I could also scale the SKScene size (zoom effect) while using the
>   normal 200x200px and 400x400px sized assets for iPad devices
>   respectively. This works and it keeps the child nodes positioning
>   working but the rendered quality of the scene/assets is not good as it
>   should be. Also, this feels like a hack and we don't want that.

This option can definitely work if your App can handle the different aspect ratios in someway. For example you could allow scrolling the scene if the scene is scaled larger than the device screen. The loss in quality occurs because you are scaling the textures larger than their expected size. You need to provide larger textures to keep the quality high when zooming. In this case you could probably just use your 600x600 images (or maybe even larger) and let it scale with zoom. For example, in my RTS Sprite-Kit game for OS X I scale the entire scene so I get the same look across all devices. And I don't lose any quality because I make sure to provide very large textures so there is no loss in quality while scaling.

---

> I could also use twice as big assets for iPad devices and double the
>   child nodes position at the runtime. In this case I would use a
>   400x400px asset for non-retina iPad devices and a new 800x800px asset
>   for retina iPad devices. While this looks great and keeps the child
>   nodes positioning working, it seems like a really big hack fixing
>   child node position during runtime with this:

This could also work, especially if your iPad requires custom layout. However, if possible avoid checking specifically for iPad and instead use the screen size to create layout rules so your nodes dynamically adjust on all screen sizes consistently (See the line of code above). Sometimes this is not possible if your iPad layout is very different from the iPhone, in which case you will have no choice but to check for iPad.

---

All three of these solution are good. I wouldn't consider any one of them "hacky." They all work for different purposes. You need to find the solution that works best for *your* game.

I would also recommend you see my two answers below. Not sure but they may help you with understanding universal positioning and scaling in Sprite Kit.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25256339/2158465

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29171224/2158465

Good luck with your game, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I don't quite understand the first part about using two nodes. Can you please expand that thought?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80701/discussion-between-epic-byte-and-damirstuhec).

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to do what you want. One approach would be to use a fixed screen size on your devices. The iPhone 5 all the way up to iPhone 6+ all use a 16:9 aspect ratio for their screens. Whereas the iPad and iPhones 4s and earlier, all use a 4:3 screen aspect ratio.

Before presenting your GameScene, you can determine the screen's aspect ratio and then set a fixed view size like this for 16:9:

```
GameScene *startGame = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(736, 414)];
startGame.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
```

or this for 4:3

```
GameScene *startGame = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 768)];
startGame.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
```

The exact values really do not matter, only the ratios.

Knowing the exact screen size will allow you to place objects in more precise manner regardless of iPhone 5 screen or 6+ screen.

Comment: Thanks. Since iPhone 4S has 3:2 aspect ratio and not 4:3, what does that change? More important, I don't have a problem of positioning the nodes in a scene, but with positioning child nodes inside of a container node with predefined positions in .plist file which are stated in points.

Comment: @damirstuhec- Changing or adding various aspect ratios entails just a couple extra lines of code. As for positioning of the children, I do not understand your question. Knowing the absolute screen size and positioning the parent, gives you a clear picture about its children as well. The biggest hurdle when dealing with various screen sizes is the amount of screen real estate. Having an iPad screen size of 1024x768 compared to an iPhone 4s screen size of 480x320 is where the issues arise from. Setting a fixed view size all but eliminates these issues.

Comment: Can we continue this discussion in chat?

Comment: @damirstuhec - I can't really chat right now but please do email me. My email address is on my profile page.

Comment: why can't  you hack constraints?  what's the dowside of mixing spritekit and uikit objects?

Answer (score 0):

Using image assets, you can also specify iPad versions of an image.

However there's not really a way around adding some extra logic to your app, branching depending on whether or not your running on the iPad, and adjusting the position manually.

We could discuss how to best incorporate that though: I'm not a fan of this "if I'm not this device" checks all throughout the code. Create an abstract superclass and two subclasses, each handling layout (or whatever you may want to call it) for one interface idiom. You will the only need to check once (when instantiating these) and polymorphism will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software as [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com) to dynamically generate texture perfectly sized to your need.

All you have to do is to define the `frame`' dimensions for each of your devices.

Comment: I don't see how would that help me with child node positioning.